# hosting images in express with image urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have an array of urls that I want to host in my backend. I couldn't find anything related to hosting images with their urls in express so I thought of an idea. I would get the image's buffer with axios and send that

```js
const images = [
 { name: "cow",     url: "https://somewhere.com/cow.png" },
 { name: "chicken", url: "https://somewhere.com/chicken.png" }
]

const express = require("express")
const app     = express()
const port    = 4000

const axios   = require("axios")

app.listen(port, () => { console.log("Online") })

images.forEach(image => {
 app.get(`/${image.name}.png`, (res, req) => {
  const getBuffer = async (url) => {
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
     try {
       const response = await axios({
         method: 'GET',
         url: url,
         responseType: 'stream',
       });

       const buffer = response.data

       resolve(buffer)
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   })
  }

  res.sendFile(getBuffer(res.url))
 })
})
```

But I think there is a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

When you use `responseType` as `stream`, you can forward the data stream to express response object directly:

```js
const express = require("express")
const axios = require("axios")

const app = express()
const port = 4000

const images = [
  { name: "cow", url: "https://somewhere.com/cow.png" },
  { name: "chicken", url: "https://somewhere.com/chicken.png" }
]

app.get('/images/:name', async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params
  const image = images.find(img => img.name === name);

  if (!image) {
    return res.status(404).send()
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: image.url,
      responseType: 'stream',
    });
    response.data.pipe(res)
  } catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message)
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => { console.log("Online") })
```

Now you can try with `http://localhost:4000/images/cow`